# Legality/common practice when calling APIs in an R package?

Tags: machine-learning, r

Without getting into too much detail, for a personal project, I have built a model in R that will call Google Maps Platform API  [see here](https://developers.google.com/maps) to pull driving times for a user’s given input and perform a useful algorithm on the pulled results.  I am considering developing this into an R package for users to install from GitHub or submitting to CRAN to be directly installable from R.  The Google API requires an individual API key acquired from signing up on Google’s site.  The user is required to input their own API key before calling the model to run.

I have two questions about the legality, responsibilities, and overall common practice when it comes to making a package available that has an option to call a third party API:

1. First, how would I find/know if this violates any terms of use, and what are the common practices of documentation/sourcing if I develop this into a package for public use?
2. Second, I worry about potential issues with the pricing.  Since the API charges the API key’s account for each pull (however it currently gives you $200 credit each month which equates to thousands of pulls), I am concerned about users disregarding this or even bugs in the code.  I have considered adding stoping conditions that require the user to acknowledge that they are calling a function that will pull from the API and require a keyboard input to continue, but I can foresee potential issues with this.

Any thoughts or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think https://community.rstudio.com/ might be a better site for you to ask this question.